# Cast one class to another one, from what extended my class

Tags: java

I have some class PERSONINFO and another class

```
public class LotusUser extends PERSONINFO {

}
```

In my code I have variable `person` with type `PERSONINFO` and I want to cast it to the `LotusUser`:

```
LotusUser lu = (LotusUser) person;
```

But it's fails with exception 
java.lang.ClassCastException lotus.PERSONINFO cannot be cast to users.LotusUser.

How to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: I hope that you _don't_ have a `class` named in block caps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `LotusUser` is a subclass of `PERSONINFO`, all `LotusUser` instances are also `PERSONINFO` instances, but **not** all `PERSONINFO` instances are `LotusUser` instances. (Just like all cats are animals, but not all animals are cats.) They may be just `PERSONINFO`, or they may be `GlarbleThorp` (another subclass of `PERSONINFO` I just created). So in the general case, unless you know that the `PERSONINFO` you have is actually a `LotusUser` (or `LotusUser` subclass), you can't cast your reference to that instance to `LotusUser`, because it may not be one.

You fix it by only trying to cast `PERSONINFO` references to `LotusUser` references for objects you **know** are actually `LotusUser`s (you can check with `instanceof`, but it's better if that knowledge comes from the logic of the code) or, ideally, by writing your code such that you don't need to do the cast at all. Casting is a last-resort option when you've exhausted your other options. (Sadly, even though it's a last-resort, you do end up there fairly frequently, although modern Java with generics and such is a **lot** better than Java used to be.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You have to understand, that even though each an every instance of LotusUser is an instance of PERSONINFO, not each instance of PERSONINFO is automatically an instance of LotusUser.

So, you'll need to check whether it is, before you cast:

```
if ( person instanceof LotusUser){
  LotusUser user = (LotusUser)person;
  // rest of your code
}
else{
 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid type");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `LotusUser` *is a* `PERSONINFO`, but it does not work the other way round, that is, a `PERSONINFO` *might not* be a `LotusUser`.

For the cast to fail, it means that whatever `PERSONINFO` object you are providing, it is not in actuality a `LotusUser`. It could be a `PERSONINFO` class or some other class which extends it.

You could use the `instanceof` operator to see if `person` is an instance of the `LotusUser` class, but that does have its pitfalls:

```
if(person instanceof LotusUser) {
    LotusUser lu = (LotusUser)person;
}
else {
    //Todo when casing fails.
}
```